# Laptop overheats when connected to the wall plug, but not when using battery

Tags: battery, overheating, charger

Especially when playing CS:GO CPU temperatures reach 95 but when I unplug the charger and use only the battery, the temperatures remain around 85. The game runs smoothly in both cases.

Comment: Are you using the proper charger that came with the laptop, or a replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Check your power settings.  I suspect you are using a high performance mode while plugged into AC.  While you are on battery, it is probably using a lower performance plan to conserve power.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the computer is trying to display 300 frames per second when plugged in. I set the maximum fps to 60, and overheating is solved.